# -bash: -sudo: command not found

Tags: random

Some dependencies were missing when I installed THC Hydra. I found [this site](http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Thc-hydra) which directs me to install the missing package:

```
sudo apt-get install libsvn-dev libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev
```

But when I try this, I receive the following error message:

```
-bash: -sudo: command not found
```

I tried searching the web for how to install the `sudo` command, but I cant find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: This may not be the best site to ask, as it's more a question of unix paths and package management.  probably a better fit for unix.stackexchange.com or askubuntu.com

Comment: More to the point, does your distribution *have* apt-get ?

Comment: haha shadur.. good question.  the apt-get command was also not found

Comment: thanks rory, ill post the same question there as well and keep checking here just in case someone knows

Comment: @thisisjnd no worries, a q. would be which version of linux are you using? If it's fedora based it would be yum that you're looking for rather than apt-get...

Comment: @thisisjnd since you posted on a different site, you should delete this question. posting your question on multiple sites (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125194/bash-sudo-command-not-found http://askubuntu.com/questions/448957/bash-sudo-command-not-found) is called cross-posting and is highly, highly discouraged on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo` command is probably not installed.

```
apt-get install sudo
```